# Dynamic graph using Treap data structure

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, graph-algorithm, treap

I am trying to implement Dynamic graph using Treap data structue.

Here is node structure:

```
    class TreapNode
    {
        public:
                int key;
                int priority;
                TreapNode* left, *right;
                vector<int> neighbourNode;
                
                TreapNode(int key)
                {
                    this->priority = 0;
                    this->key = key;
                    this->left  = nullptr;
                    this->right = nullptr;
                }
                
                TreapNode()
                {}
                
                TreapNode* addNode(TreapNode*&,int);
                void updateNode(TreapNode*&,int,int);
     };
```

When I want to add neighbouring node to particular node,

1. I search the node , and then add neighbouring node to search  node's  `vector<int> neighbourNode` through `updateNode()`, in the following way.

> searchAddress->neighbourNode.push_back(x);

But my professor says, store address of `vector<int> neighbourNode` in the node.

1. Is it going to reduce my TreapNode size ?
2. How to store address and access it ? I tried this way in TreapNode class but it is giving `neighbourNode` undefine error.

> int* neighbourNodeAddress = neighbourNode.data()

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are you sure your professor didn't mean to store the addresses of the *nodes*, rather than the vector containing the nodes? That would make more sense given the return value of `addNode`.

Comment: @Botje :  my professor saying , store address of vector<int> neighbourNode in TreapNode.  I am returning head node through addNode() that's why its return type is TreapNode*.

Comment: @Botje : `addNde()` just add node with priority as 0.  Adding edges between nodes and adding neighbour is done through `updateNode()`

Comment: Storing a `vector<int>*` instead of a `vector<int>` will save either two pointers or two  size+capacity numbers in your `TreapNode`, but you still have to store them in the heap-allocated `vector<int>`. You also need an extra pointer dereference to get to your neighbours. It is a questionable optimization, I would say.